# spring boot embedded tomcat how to rotate console output

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot ver : 1.4.1

I want to rotate the console output on a daily basis.
I am trying to achieve this w/o any OS level utilities.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add add a `logback.xml` file to your application to configure a [TimeBasedRollingPollicy](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy).

Comment: Thanx for your reply. This is for the console output (ConsoleAppender), not named log files.

TimeBasedRollingPollicy still applies ?